# How do I get a really good defense on Clash Of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When ever I get attacked I always lose 20 trophies. One night I lost 50 trophies due to a bad defense. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you included what stage you are in Clash of Clans or your town hall level it would be helpful .

Comment: Town hall level 6

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to use a hybrid base (defending trophies and resources). You should only have Defenses, Storages and your Town Hall. If you find and builders huts or barracks, be sure to put them outside your walls. Make sure not to use double walls as these are not effective against wall breakers because of their splash damage. Use layers of walls and keep buildings in separate segments of walls. Make sure that your Defenses are spread out and check that your Air Defenses have good coverage. Keep splash damage defenses in the centre of your base and make sure to protect them. Keep archers or wizards in your clan castle and position it in the centre of your base. Keep all buildings in the outside of your base close to the wall to receive maximum protection.